# Finding all non-equivalent permutations for vectors of length k taking n possible values

Tags: r, algorithm, function, permutation, combinatorics

I have a function that takes an input vector of length k, where each element in the vector can take up to n values.

Generally k will be in the range 6:10, and n in the range 2:(k-1).

For any given (n,k) there will be n^k-1 permutations of possible vectors.

Currently I am mapping each of the integers 0:(n^k-1) to a unique permutation and evaluating the function at that permutation to find the optimal input vector over all possible vectors.

For example, with n=3 and k=6 the mapping would be:

```
0:1,1,1,1,1,1
1:1,1,1,1,1,2
2:1,1,1,1,1,3 
3:1,1,1,1,2,1
...
728:3,3,3,3,3,3
```

However, for my purpose some of the permutations are equivalent.  You can think of the vector as an allocation of k elements among n classes.

Two permutations A and B are equivalent if the following both hold:

> 1. All elements in A that share a class, also share a class in B.
> 2. All elements in A that do not share a class, also do not share a class in B.

For example:
With n=2 and k=6, the vectors

```
1,2,1,1,2,1 
2,1,2,2,1,2
```

are equivalent.  In both vectors, elements {1,3,4,6} share a class and elements {2,5} share a class.

With n=3 and k=6, the vectors

```
1,2,3,1,2,3
1,3,2,1,3,2
2,3,1,2,3,1
2,1,3,2,1,3
3,2,1,3,2,1
3,1,2,3,1,2
```

are all equivalent.

My aim is to find a more efficient way of finding the optimal vector than trying every input in the range 1:(n^k-1).

I can see two possible ways forward:

Option 1.  Enumerate every possibility and then filter out all the equivalent vectors.

Option 2:  Reduce the range I need to check in advance.  For example, for n=3, k=6, I am fairly confident (but haven't proven) that I won't need to check anything above 161:1,2,3,3,3,3 and there should be some equivalent permutations within the range 1:161 as well.

I much prefer Option 2.

The ideal solution is a function of (n,k) that outputs a list of vectors representing the intervals in 1:n^k-1 that I need to check.  Almost as good would be a function of (n,k) that outputs the largest integer/vector in 1:n^k-1 that I need to check.

As a starting point, here is some sample R code:

```
vectorFromID <- function(id, n, k) {
  if(id >= n^k) {
    stop('ID too large!')
  }
  remainder <- id
  elements <- list()
  for(i in (k-1):0) {
    elements[[k-i]] <- (remainder  %/% (n ^ i))+1
    remainder <- remainder %% (n ^ i)
  }
  return(unlist(elements))
}

vectorToID <- function(inputVector, n, k) {
  total <- 0
  for(i in 0:(k-1)) {
    total <- total + (inputVector[i+1]-1) * (n ^ ((k-1)-i))
  }
  return(total)
}

# generate all possible vectors for n=3, k=6
all_vectors <- Map(function(x) vectorFromID(x, 3, 6), 0:728)
```

---

Edited to add an R implementation of the recursive solution, and benchmarking of the two solutions.

```
enum <- function(v=NULL, n, k, maxv=0) {
  if (k == 0) {
    return(list(v))
  } else {
    acc <- list()
    for (i in 1:min(n, maxv+1)) {
      acc <- c(acc, enum(c(v,i), n, k-1, max(i,maxv)))
    }
    return(acc)
  }
}
res2 <- enum(NULL, 3, 6, 0)
```

Both solutions produce equivalent output, but for larger values of k & n the recursive solution is much faster.  Below, time1 refers to the time in seconds the recursive solution takes.

```
n: 2 k: 6 rows1: 32 rows2: 32 match: TRUE time1: 0.02 time2: 0.05
n: 3 k: 6 rows1: 122 rows2: 122 match: TRUE time1: 0 time2: 0.51
n: 4 k: 6 rows1: 187 rows2: 187 match: TRUE time1: 0.01 time2: 3.32
n: 5 k: 6 rows1: 202 rows2: 202 match: TRUE time1: 0 time2: 16.8
n: 2 k: 7 rows1: 64 rows2: 64 match: TRUE time1: 0.02 time2: 0.11
n: 3 k: 7 rows1: 365 rows2: 365 match: TRUE time1: 0 time2: 1.83
n: 4 k: 7 rows1: 715 rows2: 715 match: TRUE time1: 0.05 time2: 19.62
n: 5 k: 7 rows1: 855 rows2: 855 match: TRUE time1: 0.04 time2: 277.81
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you have done your comparison, but I find that these two methods do not give the same results. The method that I proposed results in far more unique combinations than the other method(e.g. n=5,k=7 has 4875 unique, not 855; n=3,k=6 has 162 unique, not 122).

Comment: Your solution as written produces a data frame with 122 rows, but the labels go up to 162.  Try comparing rownames(res) vs nrow(res).

Comment: You're right - my apologies. The algorithm from @deniss is quite interesting - I haven't seen a function before that uses itself in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets first choose a representative for each equivalence class. Lets say that vector p = {x_1 ... x_k} is a representative if it is lexicographical minimum from all p_i such that p_i ~ p.

Notice that x_i is in range (1..x_j + 1) forall j < i. If that doesn't hold, then we can construct equivalent p_i which is less than p lexicographically. (x_1 = 1 for the same reason)

Also, if for each i, x_i is in range (1..x_j + 1), then p is a representative.
Otherwise there is some q = {y_1 ... y_n}, such that for some k, y_i = x_i for all i < k and y_k < x_k. But for that k all values from (1..max(x_i)) are in the first k-1 elements of p. So it is y_k. But that proves p is not equivalent to q.

So p is a representative iff x_i is in range (1..x_j + 1) forall j < i. Then we can derive all such representatives with a simple recursive procedure.
Sorry for my code example is in C++, I don't know R:

```
void printResult(std::vector<int>& v){
    for (auto val : v){
        std::cout << val << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void enumerate(std::vector<int>& v, int n, int k, int max){
    if (k == 0){
        printResult(v);
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= std::min(n, max + 1); i++){
            v.push_back(i);
            enumerate(v, n, k - 1, std::max(i, max));
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

void solve(int n, int k){
    std::vector<int> v;
    enumerate(v, n, k, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this completely, but I think it gets you what you want. I have three main steps:

1. Apply `expand.grid` to supply all possibly permutations of n and k.
2. Turn values into factors, with levels based on the order of appearance. Then, turn these back into a numeric value (in the loop). e.g. `c(1,2,3,1,2,3)` and `c(3,2,1,3,2,1)` would be returned as `c(1,2,3,1,2,3)` and `c(1,2,3,1,2,3)` (i.e. equivalent) due to the similar order of factor levels.
3. Return only unique combinations. With `n=3` and `k=6`, the number of unique combinations is reduced from 729 to 162:

#### Function `combnmix`:

```
combnmix <- function(n,k){
  tmp <- lapply(as.list(rep(n, k)), seq)
  res1 <- expand.grid(tmp)
  res2 <- NaN*res1
  for(i in seq(nrow(res1))){
    levs <- unique(c(res1[i,]))
    res2[i,] <- as.numeric(factor(res1[i,], levels=levs))
  }
  res3 <- unique(res2)
  res3
}

res <- combnmix(3,6)
res
```